# Ansible - Is it possible to loop over a list of objects in input within a playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a playbook which is managing to create some load balancers.

The playbook takes a configuration YAML in input, which is formatted like so:

```
-----configuration.yml-----

 virtual_servers:

   - name: "test-1.local"
     type: "standard"
     vs_port: 443
     description: ""
     monitor_interval: 30
     ssl_flag: true

(omissis)
```

As you can see, this defines a list of load balancing objects with the relative specifications.

If I want to create for example a monitor instance, which depends on these definitions, I created this task which is defined within a playbook.

```
-----Playbook snippet-----

...
- name: "Creator | Create new monitor"
 include_role:
   name: vs-creator
   tasks_from: pool_creator
 with_items: "{{ virtual_servers }}"
 loop_control:
   loop_var: monitor_item
...


-----Monitor Task-----
- name: "Set monitor facts - Site 1"
 set_fact:
   monitor_name: "{{ monitor_item.name }}"
   monitor_vs_port: "{{ monitor_item.vs_port }}"
   monitor_interval: "{{ monitor_item.monitor_interval}}"
   monitor_partition: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['vlan_partition'] | first }}"
...

(omissis)

- name: "Create HTTP monitor - Site 1"
 bigip_monitor_http:
   state: present
   name: "{{ monitor_name }}_{{ monitor_vs_port }}.monitor"
   partition: "{{ monitor_partition }}"
   interval: "{{ monitor_interval }}"
   timeout: "{{ monitor_interval | int * 3 | int + 1 | int }}"
   provider:
     server: "{{ inventory_hostname}}"
     user: "{{ username }}"
     password: "{{ password }}"
   delegate_to: localhost
   when:
     - site: 1
     - monitor_item.name | regex_search(regex_site_1) != None

...
```

As you can probably already see, I have a few problems with this code, the main one which I would like to optimize is the following:

The creation of a load balancer (*virtual_server*) involves multiple tasks (creation of a monitor, pool, etc...), and I would need to treat each list element in the configuration like an object to create, with all the necessary definitions.

I would need to do this for different sites which pertain to our datacenters - for which I use `regex_site_1` and `site: 1` in order to get the correct one... though I realize that this is not ideal.

The script, as of now, does that, but it's not well-managed I believe, and I'm at a loss on what approach should I take in developing this playbook: I was thinking about looping over the playbook with each element from the configuration list, but apparently, this is not possible, and I'm wondering if there's any way to do this, if possible with an example.

Thanks in advance for any input you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can influence input data I advise to turn elements of `virtual_servers` into hosts.

In this case inventory will look like this:

```
virtual_servers:
  hosts:
    test-1.local:
       vs_port: 443
       description: ""
       monitor_interval: 30
       ssl_flag: true
```

And all code code will become a bliss:

```
- hosts: virtual_servers
  tasks:
   - name: Doo something
     delegate_to: other_host
     debug: msg=done
     ...
```

Ansible will create all loops for you for free (no need for `include_roles` or odd loops), and most of  things with variables will be very easy. Each host has own set of variable which you just ... use.

And part where 'we are doing configuration on a real host, not this virtual' is done by use of `delegate_to`.

This is idiomatic Ansible and it's better to follow this way. Every time you have include_role within loop, you for sure made a mistake in designing the inventory.

Comment: Hello George, thanks for your reply. The input data (the configuration.yml file) can indeed be modified, however the configuration must be performed by specific devices (F5 appliances) where I log into (`inventory_hostname`), where the newly-created virtual servers will reside. So, the `delegate_to: localhost` would become necessary in my case.

Comment: Yep, it's perfectly fine to use delegations. If you need you can use jump hosts or ssh proxy hosts for connection, but basic idiomatic way to control 'new servers which are not created yet' is to run playbook against them (in the inventory) and delegate the actual work to the hypervisor/management host.

Comment: Thanks George, I think I understand the approach. I will certainly try it